# Не могу понять как работает QPainterPath в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Разбираюсь с рисовкой в Qt, пытаюсь нарисовать свою графическую фигуру, используя `QPainterPath`. Для этого создаю класс `class PuzzlePiece : public QGraphicsPathItem`. В нём вся логика по отрисовке. Графический объект будет иметь размеры `p_size`. Я создаю объект `QPainterPath pp;`

```
pp.moveTo(-p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
pp.lineTo(-p_size / 16, -p_size / 2);
pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
                 p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 270, -90.0);
pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8 -p_size / 16,
                 p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 180, -180.0);
pp.arcTo(0, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
                 p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 0, -90.0);
pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
```

На этом этапе отрисовывается лишь часть фигуры (только 3 дуги окружности). Однако, при добавлении ещё одной строки `pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, p_size / 2);` добавляется оставшаяся часть (две горизонтальные линии).
Выглядит это как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему отрисовка происходит невсегда и от чего это зависит? Спасибо.

Полный код puzzlepiece.cpp:

```
    #include "puzzlepiece.h"
    #include <QPainter>
    #include <QDebug>

    PuzzlePiece::PuzzlePiece(ConnectorPosition north, ConnectorPosition east,
                             ConnectorPosition south, ConnectorPosition west){
        sides[0] = north;
        sides[1] = east;
        sides[2] = south;
        sides[3] = west;

        ppix = QPixmap("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Хризантема.jpg");
        p_size = 200;
        QPainterPath pp;
        constructPP(pp);
        setPath(pp);
    }

    //void PuzzlePiece::constructShape(QPainterPath &pp){
    //    pp.moveTo(-p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
    //    switch(sides[0]){
    //        case None:
    //           pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
    //           break;
    //        case Out:
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 16, -p_size / 2);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 270, -90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8 -p_size / 16,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 180, -180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(0, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 0, -90.0);
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //        case In:
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 16, -p_size / 2);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 90, 90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 16,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 180, 180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(0, -p_size / 2,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 0, 90.0);
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //    }
    //    switch(sides[1]){
    //        case None:
    //           pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, p_size / 2);
    //           break;
    //        case Out:
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 2 , -p_size / 16);
    //            pp.arcTo(p_size / 2, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 180, -90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(p_size / 2 -p_size / 16, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 90, -180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(p_size / 2, 0,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 270, -90.0);
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //        case In:
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 2 , -p_size / 16);
    //            pp.arcTo(p_size / 2 -p_size / 8, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 0, 90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(p_size / 2 -p_size / 8 -p_size / 16, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 90, 180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(p_size / 2 -p_size / 8, 0,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 270, 90.0);
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //    }
    //    switch(sides[2]){
    //        case None:
    //           pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2, p_size / 2);
    //           break;
    //        case Out:
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 16, p_size / 2);
    //            pp.arcTo(0, p_size / 2,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 90, -90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, p_size / 2 -p_size / 16,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 0, -180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, p_size / 2,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 180, -90.0);
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2, p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //        case In:
    //            pp.lineTo(p_size / 16, p_size / 2);
    //            pp.arcTo(0, p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 270, 90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, p_size / 2 -p_size / 8 -p_size / 16,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 0, 180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 180, 90.0);
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2, p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //    }
    //    switch(sides[3]){
    //        case None:
    //           pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
    //           break;
    //        case Out:
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2 , p_size / 16);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 2 -p_size / 8, 0,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 0, -90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 2 -p_size / 8 -p_size / 16, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 270, -180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 2 -p_size / 8, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 90, -90.0);
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //        case In:
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2 , p_size / 16);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 2, 0,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 180, 90.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 2 -p_size / 16, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 270, 180.0);
    //            pp.arcTo(-p_size / 2, -p_size / 8,
    //                     p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 90, 90);
    //            pp.lineTo(-p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
    //            break;
    //    }
    //}

    void PuzzlePiece::constructPP(QPainterPath &pp){
        pp.moveTo(-p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
        pp.lineTo(-p_size / 16, -p_size / 2);
        pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
                         p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 270, -90.0);
        pp.arcTo(-p_size / 8, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8 -p_size / 16,
                         p_size / 4, p_size / 4, 180, -180.0);
        pp.arcTo(0, -p_size / 2 -p_size / 8,
                         p_size / 8, p_size / 8, 0, -90.0);
        pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, -p_size / 2);
        pp.lineTo(p_size / 2, p_size / 2);
    }

    void PuzzlePiece::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget){
        painter->setClipPath(path());
        painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
        QRect b_rect = boundingRect().toRect();
        painter->drawPixmap(b_rect.x(), b_rect.y(), pixmap());
        painter->drawPath(path());
    }

    QPixmap PuzzlePiece::pixmap(){
        return ppix;
    }

    void PuzzlePiece::setPixmap(QPixmap &pix){
        ppix = pix;
        update();
    }
```

Полный код puzzlepiece.h:

```
 #ifndef PUZZLEPIECE_H
    #define PUZZLEPIECE_H
    #include <QGraphicsPathItem>


    class PuzzlePiece : public QGraphicsPathItem
    {
    public:
        enum ConnectorPosition {None, Out, In};
        PuzzlePiece(ConnectorPosition, ConnectorPosition, ConnectorPosition, ConnectorPosition);

        QPixmap pixmap();
        void setPixmap(QPixmap &);
    private:
        int p_size;
        QPixmap ppix;
        ConnectorPosition sides[4];

        void constructPP(QPainterPath &pp);
        void constructShape(QPainterPath &);
        void paint(QPainter *painter,
                  const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                  QWidget *widget = nullptr);
    };

    #endif // PUZZLEPIECE_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "configurationdialog.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "puzzlepiece.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.addItem(new PuzzlePiece(PuzzlePiece::In, PuzzlePiece::Out,
                                  PuzzlePiece::In, PuzzlePiece::Out));
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();

//    ConfigurationDialog c;
//    c.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: покажите полный код, с созданием пэинтера и тем как вы этот путь отрисовываете

Comment: просто у меня ваш код рисует что-то перевернутое) может у вас там трансляция координат идёт?

Comment: Добавил весь исходный код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код помог, у вас ошибка в методе отрисовки.

```
painter->setClipPath(path());
painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
...
painter->drawPath(path());
```

Первым действием отрисовки вы ограничиваете область отрисовки контуром пазла и только потом отрисовываете этот контур с толщиной линии 3. По факту получается, что, поскольку у линии толщина 3 пикселя вы видите лишь часть своего контура. Когда вы добавляете строку с отрисовкой вертикальной линии, то изменяется общий размер контура и вы видите те части, которые не видно было раньше.

Правильная отрисовка будет выглядеть так:

```
void PuzzlePiece::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
    painter->drawPath(path());

    painter->setClipPath(path());
    QRect b_rect = boundingRect().toRect();
    painter->drawPixmap(b_rect.x(), b_rect.y(), pixmap());
}
```

сначала рисуем контур, потом ставим огранчиение по контуру и рисуем туда пиксмап.
Пробуйте)

P.S. попробуйте включить опцию антиалиасинга для пэинтера, отрисовка будет на такой пиксельно

```
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]